# Injecting a service into another service in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Is it possible to inject one service into another service in angularJS?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Yes. follow the regular injection rule in angularjs.

```
app.service('service1', function(){});

//Inject service1 into service2
app.service('service2',function(service1){});
```

Thanks to @simon. It is better to use Array injection to avoid minifying problem.

```
  app.service('service2',['service1', function(service1) {}]);
```

Comment: I suggest using the array injection way to avoid problem when you'll want to minify your scripts in the future: `['service1', function(service1) {}]`

Comment: You can also use [`ngmin`](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) or associated grunt task.

Comment: if you wanted to access another method from the same service I presume you wouldn't want to inject the same service into the service; trying to call it using 'this' doesn't seem to work for me though, any thoughts on what is the best way of doing it? thanks!

Comment: Just wondering what if you inject 'service1' into 'service2', and also inject 'service2' into 'service1', what will happen then? What if one service's initialisation depending on the other service's initialisation?

Comment: @Xinan in that case angularjs will throw error of cyclic dependcy. So avoid it and anyways that is not a good programming practice.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.  Like this (this is a provider, but same thing applies)

```
    module.provider('SomeService', function () {


    this.$get = ['$q','$db','$rootScope', '$timeout', 
                function($q,$db,$rootScope, $timeout) {
          return reval;
    }
    });
```

In this example, `$db` is a service declared elsewhere in the app and 
injected into the provider's `$get` function.

Answer (score 5):

In order to avoid any confusion, I think it is also worth mentioning that if you are using any other services (e.g. $http, $cookies, $state) in your childService, then you also need to explicitly declare them.

e.g.

```
function() {
  var childService = function($http, $cookies, parentService) {

  // Methods inherited
  this.method1Inherited = parentService.method1();
  this.method2Inherited = parentService.method2();

  // You can always add more functionality to your child service

  angular.module("app").service("childService", ["$http", "$cookies", "parentService", childService]);

}());
```

You can either declare the services you are using inside your child in an array and then they get injected automatically, or inject them separately with the $inject annotation:

```
childService.$inject = ["$http", "$cookies", "parentService"]; 
angular.module("app").service("childService ", childService );
```