# Duplicating declarations when injecting serivces into controllers AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my controllers set up using array injection, however as the number of services that I pass to the controller increases I will be repeating each one twice - in the array and as a parameter.

I found from the following question [Injecting a service into another service in angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004760/injecting-a-service-into-another-service-in-angularjs#comment31567567_21004811) that I did not have to use array injection, which means no repeating, but it causes problems with minification. However as John Ledbetter commented, it isn't a issue if using ngmin.

My question is, if I use the following definition:

```
appControllers.controller('LoginController', function($scope, $rootScope, $localStorage, myService1, myService2) {
```

Instead of:

```
appControllers.controller('LoginController', [ '$scope', '$rootScope', '$localStorage', 'myService1', 'myService2',
  function($scope, $rootScope, $localStorage, myService1, myService2) {
```

Is there any implications other than needing to use ngmin when minifying with grunt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using grunt for concatenating and minifying my angular files. The answer to your question is no, there will be no implications other than needing to use ngmin.

I recommend you use [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) which has improved to be much better than ngmin.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to double check before potentially hitting further issues in the future.