# How can I inject a service into another service with specific function names

Tags: angularjs

Lets say I have my code as below

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("Customerfactory", Customerfactory); 

app.service("Address",Address);
app.service("Phone",Phone);

app.service("customer",customer);
app.service('CreateFactory',CreateFactory);
```

I want to inject `Address` and `Phone` service into `customer` service and then `customer` service into `createFactory` service using Array Injection technique.

Any thoughts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Injecting a service into another service in angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004760/injecting-a-service-into-another-service-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
app.service("customer",['Address','Phone',function(Address,Phone){


}]);

app.service('CreateFactory',['customer',function(customer){

}]);
```

Comment: Thanks @Anik
What If I would call a function that was defined out of it.
'app.service('CreateFactory',['customer',CreateFactory(customer)]);'
Is this acceptable?
If so how can I access a variable that was defined in **Address** service in CreateFactory Service.
I am still learning AngularJs, sorry if I am wrong at anything.

Answer (score 0):

You just use the regular injection rules in Angular (following the convention for being able to minify your code):

```
app.service('service2',['service1', function(service1) {}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not using any square brackets for declaring in Angular, less bugs

```
app.service("customer", function(Address, Phone){
});

app.service('CreateFactory', function(customer){
});
```